# How can I return a more derived type from an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance

I have an interface that transforms a grid of data which I want to implement:

```
public interface ITransformable<T>
{
    T Slice(int x, int y, int width, int height);
    T Slice(Rectangle value);
    T Transpose();
    T Flip(bool horizontal, bool vertical);
    T Rotate(bool clockwise);
}
```

So I make a class that does so:

```
public class Mesh<T> : ITransformable<Mesh<T>>
{
    public Mesh<T> Transpose() { ... }
    /// etc
}
```

However, when making a more derived version of mesh, I run into an issue. For example, I have a `Heightmap` class which is a `Mesh<float>`. By making a specific implementation of T, this allows me to use operator overloads so I can add easily add two heightmaps together, for example. But when I implement it

```
public class Heightmap : Mesh<float> { ... }
```

`Heightmap`'s functions from ITransformable still return a Mesh, rather than a Heightmap. Is there any way to implement a base behavior in `Mesh`, but "change" the return type in the more derived class? I thought this was the purpose of covariance, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: If you intend to override `Transpose`, you need to make it `virtual` in `Mesh<T>`, then `override Heightmap Slice(int x, int y, int width, int height) {...}` within `Heightmap`.  If you have already tried this, please show the error message or the way it doesn't work in your question.

Comment: You need to pass way to create derived objects into base class, maybe `Mesh<T,TImpl> : ITransformable<TImpl> where TImpl:Mesh<T>, new()`

Comment: You even though the interface calls for returning a `Mesh<T>`, the implementation can still return a `Heightmap` from an overriden version of `Transpose` (needs to be marked `virtual` though).  The caller will need to cast to `Heightmap` if he needs access to specific properties/methods of that class.

Comment: It looks like @luqui had the answer I was looking for. Simply overriding the method and returning `base.Transpose()` correctly changing the typing I wanted. I feel dumb for asking now, but at least it works!

Comment: Kyle Baran: it does not look like what you asked matched what you wanted... or maybe your comment is using wrong terms - you can't override method and change return type... Anyway - consider posting answer.

Comment: Actually yeah I just tested it and it's not really working out. What I want is to implement the interface in `Mesh<T>` (so that the methods return `Mesh<T>`), but also have the option of deriving from `Mesh<T>` into a `Heightmap : Mesh<float>`, but instead of the methods returning `Mesh<float>`, they should return a `Heightmap` object, because that is the most derived form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code, it should work like charm. Replace the Methods/Exception to your own implementation.

```
  public interface ITransformable<T, out S> where S : ITransformable<T, S>
    {
        S Slice(int x, int y, int width, int height);
        S Slice(Rectangle value);
        S Transpose();
        S Flip(bool horizontal, bool vertical);
        S Rotate(bool clockwise);
    }

    public class Mesh<T, S> : ITransformable<T, S> where S : Mesh<T,S>, ITransformable<T, S>, new()
    {
        public S Slice(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public S Slice(Rectangle value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public S Transpose()
        {
           //The following will work smoothly.
           S sObject = this.Slice(10, 20, 30, 40);
           return sObject;
        }
        public S Flip(bool horizontal, bool vertical)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public S Rotate(bool clockwise)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }

    public class Heightmap : Mesh<float, Heightmap>
    {

    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Heightmap heightmap = new Heightmap();
            Heightmap map2 = heightmap.Transpose(); //This will work smoothly.
        }
    }
```